# How can i replicate this css grid in a php loop?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have this (imo) rahter complex grid that i need to make. I has to be repeatable so when item 10 is rendered, it will star over on item 1 etc. I have attached an image showing what the layout should look like.

Code is not much done at this point. Basically like this little pseudo.

html will be looking like this:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
  <div class="item">item 10</div>
  ...
</div>
```

The css i have this far is: (i believe i have to incorporate nth-child in some way)

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask]. SO isn't a free service code. Try to code a solution and then ask here posting your attemps

Comment: This is my attempt..

Comment: No this is not an attemp, this is only a loop, you don't start to code your grid inside. If you don't know how to use grid in css, try to code it statically

Comment: The PHP parts of this are somewhat irrelevant unless you know the HTML you're trying to build (and have built the CSS to style it).  Have you built a working sample of that yet?  What *HTML* and *CSS* have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Original post updated.

Comment: `style="display:grid;` != `class="grid"`. So maybe correct that, and see if there's still an issue. (That's assuming the static HTML you've shown is actually the HTML you want the PHP to output.)

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. So what's the issue now, then, specifically? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The issue is how i line up the items as described by the attached image. i would prefer to do it in css/scss utilising the nth-child or something..

Comment: well your sample HTML doesn't achieve that either as far as I can see - unless I'm mistaken? So for the time being you should take PHP out of the picture and focus on getting a grid layout you want. _Then_ go back to making some PHP code which can output that dynamically. In other words, re-focus your question.

Comment: yepp, fair enought. php is not a part of the problem here really. i have now deleted that part. i initially added it just to demonstrate that it has to be dynamic. if the items always 10, you can just style them child by child. but thats not what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (i believe i have to incorporate nth-child in some way)

You sure do! Combine it with the formula [(*an + b*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#functional_notation) and you got gold, my friend.

Sizing is just for the example, change it for your own needs.

Good luck.

```css
/* RESET */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* GRID CSS */

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 4rem;
  grid-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.item {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.item:nth-child(10n+1), .item:nth-child(10n+7) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.item:nth-child(10n+2), .item:nth-child(10n+6) {
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
}

.item:nth-child(10n+3), .item:nth-child(10n+8) {
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
  <div class="item">item 10</div>
  <div class="item">item 11</div>
  <div class="item">item 12</div>
  <div class="item">item 13</div>
  <div class="item">item 14</div>
  <div class="item">item 15</div>
  <div class="item">item 16</div>
  <div class="item">item 17</div>
  <div class="item">item 18</div>
  <div class="item">item 19</div>
  <div class="item">item 20</div> 
</div>
```